# Cannot set php session when using ajax to submit login form?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, authentication

I am using the following ajax to submit my login form without refreshing the page like so:

Ajax:

```
<script src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery/flip/jquery.flip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery/flip/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var myusername = $("#myusername").val();
        var mypassword = $("#mypassword").val();
        if (myusername == null || myusername == "" || mypassword == null || mypassword == "") {
            if (myusername == null || myusername == "") {
                document.forms["form"]["myusername"].style.border = "2px solid #963634";
            }
            if (mypassword == null || mypassword == "") {
                document.forms["form"]["mypassword"].style.border = "2px solid #963634";
            }
            $(".home_column").effect("shake");
        } else {
            // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            $.post("include/validate_login.php", {
                username1: myusername,
                password1: mypassword
            }, function (data) {
                if (data == 'login_wrong') {
                    $(".home_column").flip({
                        direction: 'lr',
                        color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)',
                        content: '<h2s1>Incorrect Login Details</h21>'
                    })
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".home_column").revertFlip()
                    }, 2500);
                } else {
                    if (data == 'login_success') {
                        $(".home_column").flip({
                            direction: 'lr',
                            color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)',
                            content: '<h2s1>correct Login Details</h21>'
                        })
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $(".home_column").revertFlip()
                        }, 2500);
                    }
                }
                $('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
            });
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

HTML form:

```
<div class="home_column" id="login_box">
<div class="login_form">
<form id="form" name="form"> 
<h21>Username</h21><br/>
<input type="text" class="login_form_front" id="myusername" name="myusername" autocomplete="off"><br/>
<h21>Password</h21><br/>
<input type="password" class="login_form_front" autocomplete="off"  id="mypassword" name="mypassword">
<br/>
<input type="button" class="buttons_login" value="Login" id="submit" name="submit">
</form> 
</div>
</div>
```

This then executes my validate_login.php page:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$tbl_name="internal_users";  
$tbl_name2="supplier_users";  

$username=$_POST['username1']; // Fetching Values from URL
$password=$_POST['password1'];

$username = stripslashes($username);  // Secure Values
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user_name = '$username' UNION
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 where user_name = '$username'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error() );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$hashed_pass = crypt($password, $Blowfish_Pre . $row['salt'] . $Blowfish_End);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {   // Check Username Exists

if($hashed_pass === $row['user_password_hash']) {   // Check Password is valid
session_start();  //Start User Session
$_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];
$sql2 = mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET user_failed_logins = '0', user_status = 'online' WHERE user_name = '".$username."'");
$result2=mysql_query($sql2); 
$sql3 = mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET user_failed_logins = '0', user_status = 'online' WHERE user_name = '".$username."'");
$result3=mysql_query($sql2); //Start User Session
session_write_close();
echo "login_success";
}else{
echo "login_wrong";   
}
}else{
echo "login_wrong";     
}  ?>
```

As you can see from my validate_login.php page I check to see if the username exists in the database and if it does, then I check to see if the password matches or not.

If the the login is successful I echo out 'login_success' otherwise I echo login_wrong and I pass this data back to the ajax script. This all works fine, I have tested whether the user login is successful or not using alert boxes previously to give me the echoed result, so I know the script works and the user is essentially logged in.

My ajax also features a jquery function where the div 'home_column' around my login form will flip and display either a login successful message or a login unsuccessful message.

If the login successful message is displayed after a short delay the user is suppose to be redirected to the dashboard.

However, when I add session_start() in my validate_login.php file to set the session for the user login then my jquery doesn't work, my jquery function where the div 'home_column' is suppose to flip doesn't happen and the redirect to the dashboard does not happen.

Only when the user manually hits refresh to refresh the page do they become logged in and get redirected to the dashboard. However the jquery function where my div 'home_column is suppose to flip is still ignored.

this all works fine if I take out session_start()

can someone please show me what I am doing wrong, thanks

Comment: Do you have any JS error? I think you forgot a `;` after the call to `flip()` function. (Just before `setTimetout()` in both cases.)

Comment: @cactus this can't possibly be a JS error as the js only stops working when I add $_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id']; if I remove this it all works fine but the user isn't logged in because I am unable to set the session

Comment: Do you have any PHP error? :) Have you tried running the PHP code without using JS/AJAX?

Comment: @cactus yes the php code works without any error when I use it without ajax

Comment: @cactus l have updated my answer, I realised that if I take out the session_start() it's actually that which is causing the issue, not the $_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];

Comment: @cactus although without session_start I am in the same situation where I cannot set the login session for the user :/

Comment: Just asking: is it normal that $sql2 AND $result2 (also ...3) call mysql_query() ?

Comment: Please read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php.

Comment: A session is a key that refers to a file on the server. For a given request the id is set, therefore the session might mismatch with AJAX (it's a different request). Your solution might solve this problem, but the only way to preserve session data async is to pass the active session id to session_id.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem to this question, it was because I needed to place session_start(); at the top of my page rather than half way down the page.